# How do I bind one combobox to the object selected in another combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am new to the data binding and WPF so I apologize if my question is rudimentary.

Let me explain my problem with a simple example:

Say a restaurant has three type of Pizzas: Mini Pizza, Ordinary Pizza and Large Pizza.
The manager wants to give customers a small gift depending on the order price.

The ordinary pizza's gift is a small key chain:

```
class pizza_ordinary : pizza
{
    Public List<string> Gifts
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string>()
            {
                "Small Keychain Blue",
                "Small Keychain Red"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

In a similar way for large pizza:

```
class pizza_large: pizza
{
 ...
     {
     "Big Keychain Yellow",
     "Big Keychain Green",
     "Big Keychain Pink"
     }
 ...
}
```

But the Mini pizza does not come with any gifts and does not have a Gifts property.

So in WPF interface we have a Combobox bound to the list of Pizzas.

How can I have a second combobox which is bound to the `Gifts` property of **selected Pizza object** in the first combo box.

and How do I **disable** the second combobox **when mini pizza is selected**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ViewModel, create a `bool` property with a `get`ter that evaluates whether the box should be enabled. e.g. `return (SelectedItem.Gifts.Count > 0);`

E.g.:

```
public bool IsSecondComboBoxEnabled
{
    get { return (SelectedItem.Gifts.Count > 0); }
}
```

On your view, bind the `IsEnabled` property of the second combo box to this property from the view model.

Like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="secondComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedPizza.Gifts}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding IsSecondComboBoxEnabled}" >
... some pretty ComboBox item styling going on here ...
</ComboBox>
```

Then when you update the `SelectedItem` from your first combo box, ensure you call `PropertyChanged` for the new property you created, to update the view.

Like so:

```
public SelectedItem SelectedPizza
{
    get { return this.selectedPizza; }
    set 
    {
        this.selectedPizza = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedPizza);
        OnPropertyChanged(() => IsSecondComboBoxEnabled);
    }
}
```

**Furthermore** Have a read into using *Value Converters* with XAML. They're really useful to have. [Here's a link.](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

In this instance you could have, let's say a `IsCollectionNotNullOrEmptyToBoolean' converter, which the name is kind of self-explanatory.

This means you wouldn't need to set up any extra ViewModel properties either, and could use the converter elsewhere in your code. **really really** advise you have a look into Value Converters.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use DataTrigger. when Gifts is Null the second ComboBox will be disabled

```
<ComboBox x:Name="PizzaCB" ItemsSource="{Binding ListPizza}">

</ComboBox>
<ComboBox x:Name="GiftCB" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=PizzaCB, Path=SelectedItem.Gifts}">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=PizzaCB, Path=SelectedItem.Gifts}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```